# Incorrect ethernet crc code

Tags: c, ethernet, crc

I am trying to use the ethernet phy on my FPGA.  I am at the point where I can receive a frame.  The frame I can see using chipscope matches the data of the frame sent from my computer which I can confirm using tcpdump. However the crc I am computing does not seem to match.  The last 4 bytes of my packet as seen on the card are 0x4b504124.  However, both my on card calculation and C++ calculation which match are 0xC3899D7. I thought the c code which I copied from somewhere was correct for ethernet. I checked it against some other c code I found and they match.  Can someone point me to a correct implementation of c code for ethernet crc, or tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
unsigned int crc32b(unsigned char *message, int sz) {
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (i < sz) {
      byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
      crc = crc ^ byte;
      for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return ~crc;
}
...
uint16_t buf[] = 
{
    0x3333, 0x0000, 0x00fb, 0x0050, 0xb624, 0x9756, 0x86dd, 0x600b,
    0xa860, 0x0035, 0x11ff, 0xfe80, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x6191,
    0xd947, 0x7f85, 0xc538, 0xff02, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000,
    0x0000, 0x0000, 0x00fb, 0x14e9, 0x14e9, 0x0035, 0x7e5c, 0x0000,
    0x0000, 0x0002, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x055f, 0x6970, 0x7073,
    0x045f, 0x7463, 0x7005, 0x6c6f, 0x6361, 0x6c00, 0x000c, 0x0001,
    0x045f, 0x6970, 0x70c0, 0x1200, 0x0c00, 0x0001
};
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)buf;
std::cout << crc32(data, sizeof(buf)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Could you include a dump of the packet you are sending? When you calculated the CRC, did you do it for the whole packet? or did you exclude the last 4 bytes?

Comment: I excluded the last 4 bytes.  The data in buf is the packet data.

Comment: Does the FPGA initialize its CRC generator with the same code (0xEDB88320)?

Comment: No it uses 0xFFFFFFFF as the initial crc.  I don't think 0xEDB88320 is the correct initial value.

Comment: You're going to need to paint a better picture of your setup. What's the intended functionality? Where is it failing? Where are these CRCs being computed? Also, post your HDL.

Comment: Also, why is your buf a bunch of int16 instead of int8 or char? You sure that's being interpreted correctly?

Comment: It is 16 bit because when I copied the tcp dump it groups everything into 16 bit blocks so it was easier to make that type of array.  I guess my question is forget about my hdl, how would I compute the Ethernet crc which would be expected after the frame I have in buf.

Comment: I personally use python's zlib.crc32.  However, that is giving me an unexpected result for some reason.  Can you post the raw tcpdump output please?

Comment: I don't have the raw tcp dump for this packet anymore.  I can get a dump for a new packet tomorrow when I go home.